# global asax and beginrequest = This server variable cannot be modified during request execution

Tags: .net, iis-7.5

Anyone knows why I'm getting this error?

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> This server variable cannot be modified during request execution. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: This server variable
>   cannot be modified during request execution.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): This server variable cannot be modified
>   during request execution.]
>   System.Web.HttpServerVarsCollection.SynchronizeServerVariable(String
>   name, String value) +3998772
>   System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetServerVarChanges(HttpContext
>   ctx) +531
>   System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.SynchronizeVariables(HttpContext
>   context) +77
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +655

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

while using an empty in global.asax? (I have code in it but the error happen even with an empty one)

```
void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 

}
```

If I remove these lines, I don't get the error.

I get that error with a hello world kind of webapp (webform or mvc3)